# JQuery Cycle pagerAnchorBuilder - list tags have different classes attached to them.

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

I'm trying to make the pagerAnchorBuilder function build this:

```
<ul id="banner_nav">
<li class="how">link code</li>
<li class="who">link code</li>
<li class="why">link code</li>
</ul>
```

I'm not sure to tell it to build the li tags with 3 different classes. Any ideas? Can this be done?

Comment: what's the error ar you getting?Can you be more specific

Comment: There is no error really. There is just no way to add a different class to each li. How  would I add that here:            pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) { 
         return '#banner_nav li:eq(' + (idx) + ') a';

Comment: Ah! now I got you in a slideshow after returning it's not possible.But you have an id in a loop based on that you can remove the old class and add a new class

Comment: Hmm. That's interesting. I will try that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could build it like this.. You'd probably want to put the class names in an array or something though:

http://jsfiddle.net/RcMJW/1/

```
pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) {
  var cssClass="";

  switch (idx) {
    case 0: 
      cssClass="how";
      break;
    case 1: 
      cssClass="who";
    break;
    case 2: 
      cssClass="why";
      break;
    default: 
      cssClass="when";
  }

  return '<li class="' + cssClass + '"><a href="#">' + idx + '</a></li>';
}
```

Comment: This helped me solve a similar problem but I think you need to edit your code as the case statements need to go up from 0 to 2...

Comment: I will do. Just a copy/paste issue. Thanks for letting me know. Feel free to vote it up!

Comment: One step ahead of you on that one ;)